# Nhibrnate POCO objects with relationships but no collections - Mutli tier

Tags: nhibernate, proxy, n-tier-architecture

This is a bit of conceptual questions but I think it’s the right place to ask it.

i am working with NHibernate for some time but I find it difficult to use the collections within the POCO objects
1. I think the proxy concept is nice but when you want o use it in multi tier architecture it become a challenge.
2. I want to add a business logic on any type of request from the DB. for example authorization restrictions etc..
3. i would like to add some business logic when i add or remove entity from a collection.

and there are some more reasons why i have problems with the collections and proxies.

i thought maybe there is a way to use the POCO object without any collections and let the service layer to handle sub queries and association etc...
i understand that the collection are needed for the Nhibernate to work but once i am out of the service layer i want to flat the objects and take out all the collections. this way i can implement my own operations and business logic.

is there any standard way to do it? do i need to attach and detach the objects? how do i create DTO object from the POCO object and copy the fields etc...

anyone have some best practices for that and did the same?

I which I could just create the POCO objects without any relationship and only let nhibernat know about those relationships via the mapping. then using the session i can control the associations between the objects.

Thanks,
Noam

Comment: I'm not sure that I fully understand your question. NH by no means 'needs' anything to work (except an ID value), so you just can ignore anything in the mapping that you don't want/need. But I guess this was not your question (at least not entirely) ?!

Comment: You don't need to always specify the collection in the mapping. As long as the other end has the many-to-one, you can manage these collections separately. I usually define the collection only for the convenience of cascade="delete".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a full control under your collection I can suggest you this approach:

1. You are using a readonly collection:

   public virtual ReadOnlyCollection ChildActions
       {
           get
           {
               return new ReadOnlyCollection(new List(childActions));
           }
       }
2. For mapping you can use backing field

   private ISet childActions;
3. To ensure your collection will never be null (avoid unnessesary checks) you can to next thing in contructor:

   childActions = new HashedSet();
4. For adding and removing items from collection you can use methods:

   ```
   public virtual void AddChildAction(ActionOnClient actionToAdd)
   {
       //some logic here

       childActions.Add(actionToAdd);
   }
   public virtual void AddChildAction(ActionOnClient actionToAdd)
   {
       //some logic here

       childActions.Remove(actionToAdd);
   }
   ```

   This approach will give you full control for your collections. Hope it helps

Comment: This looks nice i will give it a try. and will let you know what i find.